# How to inner join two table only when the conditions are true?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables-
1) 'prof_data' and 2) 'student_data'

i have 'course_id' and 'dept_id' in both tables. So i need to display all database data from both tables when prof_data.course_id = student_data.course_id AND prof_data.dept_id = student_data.dept_id .

But my problem is that the query is working but it shows a single row with same value twice.
Please help me fix this.
Thank you in advance.

Below i give my code-

```
 "SELECT * FROM `student_data` INNER JOIN `prof_data` ON student_data.course_id = prof_data.course_id AND student_data.dept_id = prof_data.dept_id";
```

*But it shows double data of a single row-(it should display one 1 row as there is only 1 row data in table where that certain conditions were met.)*

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Did you try using `SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ` with that `INNER JOIN` condition?

Comment: I did tried that distict like below- SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ...... but stil same problem

Comment: Can you be able to provide the table structure of both tables?

Comment: ok i will add both table pic here in the post.

Comment: I can't believe this wouldn't work:
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `student_data` INNER JOIN `prof_data` ON student_data.course_id = prof_data.course_id AND student_data.dept_id = prof_data.dept_id
Are you really sure?

Comment: I guess prof_data is the table where you store professor's data. Isn't there a case there are 2 proffesors with the same course_id and dept_id?

Comment: Well, first of all, your database tables break normalizations (database design principle). Both tables are not in the 3rd normal form. Secondly, you're joining tables based varchar fields (string) which make queries slow tremendously. So you need a separate ID field for both tables which should be integer. And I've seen many string based fields are set to the primary keys in your tables which are not right. And I don't believe `SELECT DISTINCT` statement does not work. However, you may try using `GROUP BY fieldname` without any aggregate functions.

Comment: @forpas yes there are two professor with the same course_id and dept_id.And i changed it to 1 professor and now the problem is fixed ,,, But what should i do incase 2 or more professors having same course_id or dept_id? :(  i am confused myself :/

Comment: @unclexo yes your right that my tables are not in 3rd normal form , i will fixed it, btw you are also right that distinct not working. It works only "when there is only 1 professor with same course id and dept id but the whole query produces results = number of profesors that got matched with the CONDITION.So can you help me about that?

Comment: BTW i have an idea , if i add another condition that if professor seesion's id which is p_id also must be equal to p_id so that it only shows for that particular professors session data .Like below-----                   "SELECT  DISTINCT * FROM `student_data` INNER JOIN `prof_data` ON student_data.course_id = prof_data.course_id AND student_data.dept_id = prof_data.dept_id WHERE prof_data.p_id=$x",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,where $x=$_SESSION['p_id'];,,,,,,,,,,But it gives error ----- """mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given"" !

Comment: If instead of `select * ...` you select only the columns in the image and use DISTINCT then there will be no problem.

Comment: i again changed the query to this-                                           "SELECT  DISTINCT * FROM `student_data` INNER JOIN `prof_data` ON student_data.course_id = prof_data.course_id AND student_data.dept_id = prof_data.dept_id WHERE p_id='$x'" ;         and it works for now.. Now i see my mistakes. Thank you @forpas @unclexo @rf1234 for your kind help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the kind people of stackoverflow i finally managed to fix my query and  though the tables need to be converted to 3NF here is the ans:

```
"SELECT  DISTINCT * FROM `student_data` INNER JOIN `prof_data` ON student_data.course_id = prof_data.course_id AND student_data.dept_id = prof_data.dept_id WHERE p_id='$x'" ;
```

Anyway Thank you Guys.